# Is it possible for two Controllers to have same center

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, alignment

Hey Guyz help me I got stuck with an alignment setting problem... I am new to Android Development and the objective I want to achieve is I am making a Music Player in which I am trying to set an ImageView to an ImageButton but what I want to set it on the center and I did not find any way below is the code which I tried..

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton
        android:alpha="50"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play_btn"
        android:background="@null"
        />
    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/Artist"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what I tried but I could not find any property like 
alignWithMatchCenter = "parent ID" or centerInParent = "parent ID "

or is it possible if I can add ImageView within ImageButton Tag?

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        <ImageView 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/imageView"
          android:src="@drawable/Artist"
          android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
      />
```

please help me friends.
Any help will be great appreciated.
Regards,
Sarosh Madara

Comment: **"...I want to set it on the center..."** : I don't understand what you mean by this. Are you saying you want the `ImageView` to overlay the `ImageButton`?

Comment: Yes I want the centers for both the Controllers to be same..

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:alpha="50"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play_btn"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/Artist"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to center a child. You could also use a `FrameLayout` and set `android:layout_gravity="center"`.